# Tensorflow Object Detection Getting Box Coordinates

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, object-detection

I'm new on the opencv and Tensorflow i'm using tfod for my object detection and i need the bounding box coordinates.How can i get them? I looked at similar questions but i didnt get it,
there is my code:

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while cap.isOpened(): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()
    
    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=5,
                min_score_thresh=.8,
                agnostic_mode=False)
                
               

    cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```